# while() loop to ask for positive input

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I am writing a function that ask the user for input and then checks if that input is infact a positive number if not it loops until a positive number is inputed and then returns that values. This is what i have so far but when it returns im getting a weird number like 20204421.000 any help?

```
/* Checks if rate is infact positive and loops until a positive number is inputed */
int checkposrate(int rentrate) 
{
    while (rentrate < 0){
        printf("Please enter the anual rental rate per square foot(must be positive number):");
        scanf("%f",&rentrate);
    }
    return rentrate;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly off-topic, but I don't like the declaration: you aren't using rentrate as an input at all, so that shouldn't be a parameter.

```
int checkposrate() {
    int rentrate;
```

Second, as others have said, you need %d instead, but I would actually use %u - this only accepts positive integers.  If you set rentrate to start as equal to 0, then it is only set by scanf when the user enters a valid unsigned integer, leaving you with this code.  Note that this assumes that zero is not a valid positive number:

```
/* Checks if rate is in fact positive and loops until a positive number is read from input */
unsigned int checkposrate() 
{
    unsigned int rent_rate = 0;
    while (rent_rate <= 0){
        printf("Please enter the annual rental rate per square foot (must be a positive integer): ");
        scanf("%u",&rent_rate);
    }
    return rent_rate;
}
```

If, on the other hand, you do want fractional rental rates, you were right with %f, but had the wrong variable types in your code:

```
double checkposrate() {
    double rent_rate = -1.0;
    while (rent_rate < 0.0 && rent_rate) {
        printf("Please enter the rental rate per sq ft: ");
        scanf("%lf", &rent_rate);
    }
    return rent_rate;
}
```

Comment: Comment on your off-topic comment: he is using C, so you should use declaration `int checkposrate(void)`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `scanf("%d", &rentrate);` to get an integer value. `"%f"` is used when you want to input a floating point number.

If you want more information about how `scanf()` works, [you can take a look in here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Answer (score 0):

`%f` is for floating point numbers(e.g. `float`, `double`). You should use `%d` instead.

Also, just like @K-ballo mentioned, your logic is wrong. You should use a `do {}while` loop, because you'd like to get the input first from the user before making your first choice.

```
do
{
   ..
   scanf("%d", &rentrate);
}while (rentrate <= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

reentrate is declared as integer, I think you want

```
    scanf("%d",&rentrate);
```

not

```
    scanf("%f",&rentrate);
```